# Having trouble logging into laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-7, laravel-authentication

I'm trying to login. With the `Auth::login` method, it works but it doesn't keep you logged in.
When I try with this `Auth::attempt` method, it gives sql error, so I researched the reason is because it is sending JSON and the MariaDB version does not accept it. But I don't know how to get around it

I will briefly explain what the login looks like. You access, enter the email and the recaptcha. Makes a request, checks if the user exists. If it exists, send a code to the email, he types it and falls into the function below to login.

With the `Auth::login` method, I tried it this way as an example in the documentation.

```
    public function validateCode(Request $request)
    {
        $email = $request->email;

        // Get user
        $user = User::whereEmail($email);

        if ($user->count() > 0) {
            $validateCode = $request->input('validateCode');

            // Get code saved in db
            $user = $user->first();
            $userCode = $user['codConfirm'];

            // Check the codes
            if ($validateCode == $userCode) {
                Auth::login($user, true);
                
                
                if(Auth::check())
                    return redirect()->route('home');
                else
                    return redirect()->action('Auth\LoginController@index');
            } else {
                return view('confirmar-usuario', ['email' => $email]);
            }
        } 
        else {
            flash('Usuário inválido')->error();

            return view('login');
        }
    }
```

That way using `Auth::attempt`, it returns the MariaDB error.

```
if(Auth::attempt($user)){
...
}
```

That way it returns null.
I thought this way makes it as I have a hash on the password. But I did a test with another user without a hash in the password and it returns null the same way

```
if (Auth::attempt(['email' => $user['email'], 'password' => $user['password']])) {
    ...
}
```

MariaDB error:

```
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '`' at line 1 (SQL: select * from `users` where `*fillable` in (name, email, password, codConfirm, office, people_type, photo, status) and `*hidden` in (remember_token) and `*casts` in (datetime) and `*connection` = mysql and `*table` = users and `*primaryKey` = id and `*keyType` = int and `incrementing` = 1 and 0 = 1 and 0 = 1 and `*perPage` = 15 and `exists` = 1 and `wasRecentlyCreated` = 0 and `*attributes` in (1, Thiago Scomparin, scompa@cantacom.com.br, ?, $2y$10$Fxq0kHJBXLQLCFeDOOtroO5CtFOX38OwwkPlguOJq3bDsOonp37RS, active, ?, 2023-02-16 13:11:19, 2023-02-17 11:15:45, SCpXC2, Escritório Cantacom, Desenvolvedor, users/o5GFWy1woLIni1x0n5J7e0SlOgvsj1y5yyTjznnO.jpg) and `*original` in (1, Thiago Scomparin, scompa@cantacom.com.br, ?, $2y$10$Fxq0kHJBXLQLCFeDOOtroO5CtFOX38OwwkPlguOJq3bDsOonp37RS, active, ?, 2023-02-16 13:11:19, 2023-02-17 11:15:45, SCpXC2, Escritório Cantacom, Desenvolvedor, users/o5GFWy1woLIni1x0n5J7e0SlOgvsj1y5yyTjznnO.jpg) and 0 = 1 and 0 = 1 and 0 = 1 and `*dateFormat` is null and 0 = 1 and 0 = 1 and 0 = 1 and 0 = 1 and 0 = 1 and `timestamps` = 1 and 0 = 1 and `*guarded` in (*) and `*rememberTokenName` = remember_token and `*accessToken` is null limit 1)
```

Model user

```
class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use HasApiTokens, Notifiable;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name',
        'email',
        'password',
        'codConfirm',
        'office',
        'people_type',
        'photo',
        'status'
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        // 'password',
        'remember_token',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be cast to native types.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $casts = [
        'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
    ];

    public static function status()
    {
        return [
            'active' => 'Ativo',
            'disabled' => 'Desativado'
        ];
    }
}
```

Auth.php

```
'guards' => [
        'web' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],

        'api' => [
            'driver' => 'passport',
            'provider' => 'users',
            'hash' => false,
        ],
    ],

'providers' => [
        'users' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\User::class,
        ],
    ],
```

Some versions

```
"php": "^7.2.5|^8.0",
"laravel/framework": "^7.29",
```

Comment: This sentence is incomplete, you are not obtaining any collection using `$user = User::whereEmail($email);` You should use `$user = User::whereEmail($email)->first();` instead.

Comment: I do the `first` afterwards, it goes inside the if. But I could do it straight

Comment: yes but when you run the if statement you have an empty collection from previous statement. You could check the sql sentence you are running by `$user = User::whereEmail($email)->toSql();`